# Database design of performance focused reputation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

**Background:**

I am trying to optimize a full Ajax driven Forum in RoR. As RoR is already not the optimal platform for a full ajax site, i am trying to optimize my sql requests and storage.

**Issue:**

The reputation for posts is based on simple likes/dislikes going from 0-100%, while primary only the last 100 votes should count PLUS 10% of the reputation of all other posts who refer/answer to that post.  Now what is the most efficient way to store that value in my database for a fast read?

**Tried solutions for `Post.reputation`:**

a) reading all joins seperately on each request. That would be reading huge join tables and counting the joins. Does that create a big server load since it loads many entries or isn't that a problem since it is basically only 1 table?

b) not using joins at all, but storing the reputation sums in `actual` (+1 on like, +0.1 on sub-like) and `potential` (+1 on like or dislike, +0.1 on sub-like or sub-dislike). Then `Post.reputation` would be `actual/potential`. At the same time i would have to still use joins for `users_posts` to limit 1 vote per post. In my eyes this would be the solution with the best performance, but is there a way in implementing the 100 vote count limit with additional variables? Because it seems i pretty much dropped the information about the order of the votes, which would be important for that.

c) basically storing all joins as in *a)* but additionally storing the reputation value in the database for the *DB read* and calculating+writing it  whenever a refering join is added. Is it a foul way of storing the same information multiple times in the DB?

**Question:**

Which solution would be the smartest storing that information in my database and accessing it quickly/often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach will be (c). Many times, in RDBMS, we do store redundant information as cache to increase performance.

Additional notes:

- Ensure that the join table has an index on [post_id, id]. This will speedup selecting the 100th record from the join table.
- Good place to do the updates is callback of the model of the join table. This will ensure that updates are within a transaction.
- In Post's has_many definition specify :order to the criteria (most likely, id desc) that gives the newest user_post first. This will simplify other queries.

Let me know if you need some schematic code.

Comment: MySQL does not have DESC indexes (corrected my answer). However that does not affect specifying :order to be DESC. In such cases MySQL will do a reverse index traversal which is quite efficient (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html).